# Fastest way to check pandas dataframe and show other elements in the other columns at the same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If there is a list of words to check...

```
word_list = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
```

and a data frame like

```
Word,Score_a,Score_b,Score_c
word5,10,15,20
word6,40,60,80
word3,40,20,10
```

What is the fastest way to find the corresponding scores for each word in the given word list?

For example, `40, 20, 10` for `'word3'`.

Comment: fastest way will be making `Word` column as index (if it is not already), and then accessing row via it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on comments above:

```
df.set_index('Word') #set Word column as index
df.loc['word5', :] # access row
```

Output:

```
 Score_a    10
 Score_b    15
 Score_c    20
```

If you don't want to set Word as index, you can also use `.iloc`:

```
df.iloc[0, :]
```

Output:

```
Word        word5
 Score_a       10
 Score_b       15
 Score_c       20
```

Note the main difference between the two (other than the fact that you can specify column name with `loc`) is that `loc`is inclusive of the last term when you specify a range.